# JavaScript closure: Uncaught TypeError: counter.value is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1JsJx1x35c0

However, when I run this code, it gives me an error

```js
var counter = (function(){
    var privateCounter = 0
  function changeBy(val){
    privateCounter += val
  }

  return {
    increment: function(){
        changeBy(1)
    },
    decrement: function(){
        changeBy(-1)
    },
    value: function(){
        return privateCounter
    }
  }
})

console.log(counter.value())
counter.increment()
counter.increment()
console.log(counter.value())
counter.decrement()
console.log(counter.value())
```

I get this

> Uncaught TypeError: counter.value is not a function

What is the explanation of this? Why it sees `counter.value()` as not a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `counter` expression evaluates to a *function*, not an object, and the function doesn't have a `value` property. If you invoked the function, an object with a `value` property would be returned, but you're not doing that.

You need to *invoke* the function immediately, as an IIFE, for the `counter` variable name to reference the returned object:

```js
var counter = (function() {
  var privateCounter = 0

  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val
  }

  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1)
    },
    decrement: function() {
      changeBy(-1)
    },
    value: function() {
      return privateCounter
    }
  }
})();

console.log(counter.value())
counter.increment()
counter.increment()
console.log(counter.value())
counter.decrement()
console.log(counter.value())
```

You can leave the function uninvoked in the beginning like you're doing now if you wanted to create multiple counters, but then, best to call it `makeCounter` instead of `counter`:

```js
var makeCounter = function() {
  var privateCounter = 0

  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val
  }

  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1)
    },
    decrement: function() {
      changeBy(-1)
    },
    value: function() {
      return privateCounter
    }
  }
};

const counter1 = makeCounter();
console.log(counter1.value())
counter1.increment()
counter1.increment()
console.log(counter1.value())
counter1.decrement()
console.log(counter1.value())

console.log('----');

const counter2 = makeCounter();
counter2.decrement();
counter2.decrement();
console.log(counter2.value())
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a closure environment on `counter` function, it has to be a IIFE. May be typo on copy and paste.
Correction:

```
`var counter = (function(){
    var privateCounter = 0
    function changeBy(val){
        privateCounter += val
    }`

    `return {
        increment: function(){
          changeBy(1)
        },
        decrement: function(){
         changeBy(-1)
        },
        value: function(){
         return privateCounter
        }
     }
})()`
```